# Extract only percentage information from text in python using regex

Tags: python, regex, percentage

I'm trying to extract only valid percentage information and eliminate any incorrect representation from a string using regular expression in python. The function should work like this,
For,

```
0-100%  = TRUE
0.12% = TRUE
23.1245467% = TRUE
9999% = FALSE
8937.2435% = FALSE
7.% = FALSE
```

I have checked a few solutions in stack overflow which only extract 0-100%. I have tried the following solutions,

```
('(\s100|[123456789][0-9]|[0-9])(\.\d+)+%')
'(\s100|\s\d{1,2})(\.\d+)+%'
'(\s100|\s\d[0-99])(\.\d+)+%'
```

All these works for all other possibilities except 0-99%(gives FALSE) and 12411.23526%(gives TRUE). The reason for space is that I want to extract only two digit numbers.

Comment: What's the logic behind your desire outputs?

Comment: What should 23.123456-45.842% evaluate to?

Comment: @Kasramvd, Want to identify percentage values in a given sentence.

Comment: @mwm314, right now FALSE as my input is not a word but a sentence. If I go one level down to the point of extracting word by word and checking, then this case will evaluate to TRUE if you omit the `\s` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The problem lied in `'+'` in the expression `'(\.\d+)+'` whereas it should have been `'(\.\d+)*'`. The first expression expects to have decimal values for any two digit percentage values whereas the second doesn't. My final version is given below.

```
'\s(100|(\d{1,2}(\.\d+)*))%'
```

You can replace `\s` with `$` for percentage values at the beginning of a sentence. Also, the versions in my question section accepted decimal values for 100 which is invalid percentage value.

Comment: `*` is not the right choice for `optional` decimal values. Anyways what about `0-100%` ?

Comment: @noob, 0 is taken care of `\d{1,2}` and 100 is taken care of the `100` in the beginning of the regex. This expression addresses my test cases. If you think there is a valid percentage test case for which this doesn't work, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Considering all possibilities following regex works.

If you just ignore the `?:` i.e non-capturing group regex is not that intimidating.

**Regex:** `^(?:(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?\-)?(?:(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?)|100))%$`

**Explanation:**

- `(?:(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?\-)?` matches lower limit if there is any, as in case of `0-100%` with optional decimal part.
- `(?:(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?)|100)` matches the upper limit or if only single number with limit of `100` with optional decimal part.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vV0qH1/3)**

---

Another version of the same regex for matching such occurrences within the string would be to remove the anchor `^` and `$` and check for non-digits at the beginning.

**Regex:** `(?<=\D|^)(?:(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?\-)?(?:(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?)|100))%`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vV0qH1/4)**

Answer (score 0):

I would not rely on regex alone - it is not meant to filter ranges in the first place.
Better look for candidates in your string and analyze them programmatically afterwards, like so:

```
import re

string = """
some gibberish in here 0-100%  = TRUE
some gibberish in here  0.12% = TRUE
some gibberish in here 23.1245467% = TRUE
some gibberish in here  9999% = FALSE
some gibberish in here 8937.2435% = FALSE
some gibberish in here 7.% = FALSE
"""

numbers = []
# look for -, a digit, a dot ending with a digit and a percentage sign
rx = r'[-\d.]+\d%'

# loop over the results
for match in re.finditer(rx, string):
    interval = match.group(0).split('-')
    for number in interval:
        if 0 <= float(number.strip('%')) <= 100:
            numbers.append(number)

print numbers
# ['0', '100%', '0.12%', '23.1245467%']
```